# Error with mysql function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a function in mysql.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `siblings` (GivenID INT) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET utf8
                DETERMINISTIC
                BEGIN

                    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children VARCHAR(1024);
                    DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;

                    SET rv = '';
                    SET queue = GivenID;
                    SET queue_length = 1;

                    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
                        SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);
                        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
                            SET queue = '';
                        ELSE
                            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
                            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
                            SET queue = q;
                        END IF;
                        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

                        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
                        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) qc
                        FROM test WHERE parent_id = front_id) A;

                        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
                            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                                SET queue_length = 0;
                            END IF;
                        ELSE
                            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                                SET rv = queue_children;
                            ELSE
                                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
                            END IF;
                            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                                SET queue = queue_children;
                            ELSE
                                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
                            END IF;
                            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
                        END IF;
                    END WHILE;

                    RETURN rv;
                    END $$
```

Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6cc4

It works fine when I create it using `MySql WorkBench`, but fails to work in `phpmyadmin` / custom statement from php. Even the mentioned `fiddle` fails with some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because `DELIMITER` keyword is a function of the command line mysql client thats why it worked on MySQL workbench and not on PHPMyAdmin.

Its not a regular MySQL language feature. It won't work if you tried to pass it through a programming language API to MySQL. I think PHPMyAdmin has other methods to specify a non-default delimiter.

Comment: I tried it without delimiter as well. Please check the fiddle for the same, but the error persists, even though I could make it in native php call, but not in phpmyadmin / fiddle.

Comment: don't see anything on sql fiddle, it does not set properly try again and paste what phpmyadmin returns as error.